# How to customize PicketLink AuthenticationFilter?

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, picketlink

I have PicketLink installed and running on my web application, but it seems like I cannot protect resources like folders by group or role.  The PicketLink AuthenticationFilter (org.picketlink.authentication.web.AuthenticationFilter) does not provide any way to say which url-pattern belongs to which group or role.  How would I protect the admin directory so that only users in the admin group can access it?  Right now, if you are logged in you can access everything.

web.xml file:

```
        <filter>
            <filter-name>PicketLinkAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.picketlink.authentication.web.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>

            <init-param>
                <param-name>authType</param-name>
                <param-value>FORM</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>PicketLinkAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/standarduser/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

I tried to create my own custom AuthenticationFilter but I couldn't.   I would really wish that I could do something like in Spring.  Something like this or using the IDM functions like hasRole or isMember:

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/member/*" access="ADMIN,STANDARDUSER" />
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. So I made my own custom filter to check for the group and role after the picketlink filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I completely misunderstand what you're trying to do, I think you can do what you want via the programmatic configuration interface. [See the docs section 12.2](https://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/latest/reference/html-single/#chap-Identity_Management_-_Configuration)

```
public class HttpSecurityConfiguration {

public void configureHttpSecurity(@Observes SecurityConfigurationEvent event) {
    SecurityConfigurationBuilder builder = event.getBuilder();

    builder
        .http()
            .forPath("/*.jsf")
                .authenticateWith()
                    .form()
                        .loginPage("/login.jsf")
                        .errorPage("/loginFailed.jsf")
            .forPath("/admin/*")
                .authorizeWith()
                    .role("Administrator");
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome, this was not available under version 2.6 but now it was added to version 2.7. I'll try it!  my project is currently working using a custom filter and also let's me do some other custom things too.

Comment: Thanks it's working! How do I authorize multiple groups and roles per path?.authorizeWith().group("users,admins")

Answer (score 2):

Like previously said, the AuthenticationFilter is only about authentication.

PicketLink Team is working in a full Servlet Security support, which will provide among other things role and group based authorization for the URIs of your application.

For now, I would suggest you to create your own filter.